# How to Disable Tor and Use the Tor Browser as a Privacy Hardened Firefox

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

I know this question has been asked multiple times here, but they are all very outdated (5+ years old), and none of the answers work with the latest versions.

I am specifically asking for solutions to the latest stable release version of `Tor Browser` as I am concerned about Firefox [bundling adware](https://www.theverge.com/2021/10/7/22715179/firefox-suggest-search-ads-browser) inside its browser, and I am unwilling to accept that.

Currently, Tor can be successfully disabled on [Tor Browser 10.5.10](https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/10.5.10/) (after disabling automatic update) with these steps:

1. Setup the following environment variables - `TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1` and `TOR_TRANSPROXY=1`.
2. Create a new file `autoconfig.js` with the following content:

> pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
> pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);

3. Create a new file `firefox.cfg` with the following content:

> // Disable Tor Permanently
> lockPref("extensions.torlauncher.start_tor", false);
> lockPref("network.dns.disabled", false);
> lockPref("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", false);
> lockPref("network.proxy.type", 0);

4. On macOS, copy autoconfig.js to `Tor Browser.app/Content/Resources/defaults/pref`
5. On macOS, copy firefox.cfg to `Tor Browser.app/Content/Resources/`

This works great with `Tor Browser v10.5.10`, but not with the latest Tor Browser v11.0.1.

What needs to be done to disable Tor in Tor Browser v11.0.1 (and above) completely?

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked, but you can try this https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/#comment-4509260

Comment: Steps in it don't work for the newer versions.

Comment: The information on that website is for v9. It doesn't work for v11.

Answer (score 1):

This works in v11.0.11. Set the following in about:config

- network.dns.disabled = false
- extensions.torlauncher.start_tor = false
- network.proxy.socks = space " "